# Why does setNeedsLayout() + layoutIfNeeded() not always trigger a layout pass?

Tags: ios, uitableview, layout, autolayout, layoutsubviews

#### A simple experiment:

I have a `UITableView` with the following data source method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let identifier = "MyCellID"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) 
               as! MyCustomCell

    cell.setNeedsLayout()
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()

    cell.setNeedsLayout()
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()

    return cell
}
```

In my subclassed table view cell I override `layoutSubviews()` as follows:

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("Cell did layout its subviews.")
    }
}
```

When the table view requests a new reusable cell by calling `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` on the data source the log output in the console is only

> `Cell did layout its subviews.`

for that cell.

#### Why is this line not printed twice?

---

It is my understanding that calling `setNeedsLayout()` on any view invalidates the layout for that view and calling `layoutIfNeeded()` triggers a layout pass — i.e. a call of `layoutSubviews()` — if and only if the layout is invalid. Thus, calling the two methods

```
setNeedsLayout()
layoutIfNeeded()
```

should always result in a `layoutSubviews()` call. What's my error in reasoning here?